# Issue Using Date Criteria in a Dlookup function in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset, filtered-lookup

I am checking in the table "weekly data" for a specific date stored in the first row of the table "daily data":

```vb
Private Sub Data_Update_Click()

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rstw As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = Application.CurrentDb
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("Data daily", dbOpenDynaset)
    Set rstw = db.OpenRecordset("Data Weekly", dbOpenDynaset)

    With rst
        .MoveFirst

        Dim date_check As Date
        date_check = DLookup("[ID test]", "Data Weekly", "[weekly date] = '" & .Fields("daily date") & "'")

.........
```

The criteria is causing the problem, cannot find the right syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
date_check = DLookup("[ID test]", "Data Weekly", "[weekly date] = #" & Format(.Fields("daily date").Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#")
```

but date_check must be a *Variant* as DLookup can return *Null*.

Comment: thanks for your answer Gustav. i am using european format dates such as 26.01.2017 for today's date. i am trying to adapt it to your suggestion but could not make it work so far

Comment: my bad Gustav, actually it is perfectly working with european dates as well!. thanks for your help!

Comment: You should not "adapt" it. The specified format (ISO sequence) is the preferred for SQL, and is not related to your local settings for display of dates.