# VBA in Access - Duplicate Entries Msg Box

Tags: vba, ms-access

Can anyone help me identify what's wrong with this code? If I change DOB in the table to short text and DIM it as a string, the code works. But, with DOB as a date field, DIM as date, I am getting this error message.

"Run-time error '3464'
Data Type mismatch in criteria expression"

When I click on debug, the line bolded below is highlighted in yellow.

```
Private Sub DOB_AfterUpdate()
Dim DOB As Date
Dim FirstName As String
Dim LastName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String
Dim PIN As Integer

'Assign the entered customer name and  address  to a variable
NewJII = Me.FirstName.Value
NewJII2 = Me.LastName.Value
NewDOB = Me.DOB.Value
stLinkCriteria = "[FirstName] = " & "'" & NewJII & "' and [LastName] = " & "'" & NewJII2 & "' And [DOB] = " & "'" & NewDOB & "'"

**If Me.FirstName & Me.LastName & Me.DOB = DLookup("[FirstName]", 
"TblPersonLog", stLinkCriteria) Then**

  MsgBox "This Customer, " & stLinkCriteria & " has already been entered in database." _
            & vbCr & vbCr & "with DOB " & NewDOB & "" _
            & vbCr & vbCr & "Please check Customer name and Date Of Birth again.", vbInformation, "Duplicate information"
   Cancel = True
End If



End Sub
```

Really appreciate any guidance!! I've been trying to troubleshoot this for days. Not very strong in VBA.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41832756/issue-using-date-criteria-in-a-dlookup-function-in-access-vba   Dates require `#` not `'`

Comment: If Me.FirstName = DLookup("[FirstName]", "TblPersonLog", stLinkCriteria) Then          
 it's this line that's giving me problems

Comment: That's exactly what is addressed in the link I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't use `DLookup` that way. Second, if you wish to cancel, use the *BeforeUpdate* event. Third, as stated by Tim, use the correct syntax for the date criteria.

Thus, it could be something like this:

```vb
Private Sub DOB_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim FirstName       As String
    Dim LastName        As String
    Dim NewDOB          As Date
    Dim stLinkCriteria  As String

    If Not IsNull(Me!DOB.Value) Then
        ' Assign the entered customer name and DOB to variables.
        FirstName = Nz(Me!FirstName.Value)
        LastName Nz(Me!LastName.Value)
        NewDOB = Me!DOB.Value

        stLinkCriteria = "[FirstName] = '" & FirstName & "' And [LastName] = '" & LastName & "' And [DOB] = #" & Format(NewDOB, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#"
        Cancel = Not IsNull(DLookup("[FirstName]", "TblPersonLog", stLinkCriteria))

        If Cancel = True Then
            MsgBox "This Customer, " & FirstName & " " & LastName & ", has already been entered in the database" _
                & vbCr & vbCr & "with DOB " & NewDOB & "." _
                & vbCr & vbCr & "Please check Customer name and Date Of Birth again.", vbInformation, "Duplicate information"
        End If
    End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered if you feel so.